# TinyIoc register and interface with multiple types

Tags: c#, nancy, tinyioc

I am trying to register a base interface `IService` in `TinyIoc`

Currently I have multiple classes that inherit from `Iservice`

for example `AuthenticationService` and `RestService` both inherit from base class `Service` which implements `Iservice`

The way I am doing it is like this, registering each service separately.

```
container.Register<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
container.Register<IRestService, RestService>();
```

since they both inherit from  `Service : IService` is there a way to register both in one call or do I have to seperately register each service?

Answer (score 0):

There's a overload for the `Register` method that accepts a `Func`, that you can use to determine which concrete type do you want to return:

```
var decision = true;
container.Register<IService>((c, npo) =>
{
    // Change it to whatever logic you need to decide which service should be returned
    if (decision)
        return new AuthenticationService();
    else
        return new RestService();
});

var instance = container.Resolve<IService>();
```